# Microservices - Security Implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, api-gateway

Is it better to handle security at a microservice level or at api-gateway level in microservice deployments? Are there scenarios where one would be more apt than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/) article:

> A major benefit of using an API Gateway is that it encapsulates the internal structure of the application. Rather than having to invoke specific services, clients simply talk to the gateway.

This simply means that clients talk to microservices through an API gateway and that gateway handles all the requests which comes for any of the underlying services.

So, I think that if you need to do any authorisation for a request, it is beneficial to do it at API gateway itself because this way, an unauthorised request never reaches your service.

But that can't be a complete a solution as well. Let's consider a service which actually authenticate a user. This service will always be accessed by users who haven't been authorised yet, so, it makes sense to implement security for this service at the service level instead of the API gateway.

Also, consider a service which create orders. What if any internal service can call this service and create an order, without requiring any token (or any other authentication process). Now this problem can be solved using many ways like:

- Restricted network access to internal services, such at not other service except API gateway can access this service.
- Add/Proxy the security token (like JWT) to all services and validate a request against that token in each of the service.

Of course this is a high level overview, are my thoughts and I am willing to see what others have to say.

Comment: Thank you Shubham! This is very useful

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's the common way tu use some kind of reverse proxy as security gateway, that generates some kind of security tokens, like SAML.

Otherwise for example, if you have some chained calls, like micro service user calls micro service transaction log, each and every microservice does the auth for itself again and again. This can get quite expensive.

Comment: Thanks Dudelilama